# Convex polytope volume and centroid calculation

Tags: computational-geometry, high-dimensional, convex-hull

I have troubles imagining how to compute a volume and centroid of an n-dimesional convex polytope.

For a polygon (especially for convex polygon) the area and centroid are described in ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid)) by 
$$
A= \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=0}^n (x_iy_{i+1}-x_{i+1}y_i)
$$
For k-dimensional case the volume ([Volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume)) is 
$$
\int\limits_a^bA(h)\mathrm{d}h
$$
Still, maybe I need another cup of coffee to be able to transfer this into code. So i was thinking about this
$$
A= \sum\limits_{d=1}^k \sum\limits_{\forall d' \neq d} \frac{1}{k}\sum \limits_{i=0}^n (p^{(d)}_i p^{(d')}_{i+1}-p^{(d)}_{i+1}p^{(d')}_i)
$$
with $p^{(d)}$ beeing a variable in dimesion $d$ 
But I do not trust myself ;-) Do you have an idea ?

As for centroids, I do not understand where the factor $\frac{1}{6}$ comes from
$$
C_x = \frac{1}{6 A} \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (x_i + x_{i + 1}) (x_i y_{i + 1} - x_{i + 1} y_i)
$$
and would blindly guess
$$
C_{(d)} = \frac{1}{(k+1)! A} \sum\limits_{\forall d' \neq d}\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (p_i^{(d)} + p_{i + 1}^{(d)}) (p_i^{(d)} p_{i + 1}^{(d')} - p_{i + 1}^{(d)} p_i^{(d')})
$$
Do you think this is right? I appriciate any feedback!
Thanks!

Comment: You might check the MathOverflow question, ["Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope"](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/).

Answer (score 3):

If the dimension is not too high, you can use a triangulation library (e.g. [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Convex_hull_d/Chapter_main.html)) to decompose the polytope into n-dimensional simplices; calculating the volume of a simplex has a simple [formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Geometric_properties)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still, I need to figure out, if I'm dealing with simplices - I'm not sure, that every convex hull is a simplex.

Comment: a n-d simplex has exactly n+1 vertices so no, not every convex hull is a simplex. But every polytope can be partitioned into the union of disjoint simplices (e.g. in 2d, [triangulating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) an arbitrary polygon). Then, to get the total area, add up the areas of all the triangles.